# Can prerelease NuGet packages be displayed in VS Package Manager UI?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, semantic-versioning

I'm using a custom NuGet feed for deploying own NuGet packages.
I'm using [semver](http://semver.org/) so my CI server is generating a deploying new prerelease packages on every build. Those prerelease packages are obviously not visible by default in Package Manager.

**Is there a way to specify on package / feed / global  level that prerelease  packages should appear under Updates tab in Package Manager?**

If I install a prerelease package by for example editing `packages.config` file my package is clearly marked in Package Manager with red 'Prerelease' label, so the manager understands versioning properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out that it is possible to update specific package to a prerelease version using **Powershell console**. `Update-Package` command takes an `-IncludePrerelease` flag, and it is possible to update dependencies for all projects using a single command:

```
Update-Package <Package-Id> -IncludePrerelease
```

The above command will update to the latest prerelease version. If you want to update to a certain version you can specify it as below:

```
Update-Package <Package-Id> -IncludePrerelease -Version <version-number>
```

UPDATE:

**NuGet 1.7** shows prerelease packages in the Manage NuGet packages dialog.